# Attach Sqlite Database in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, connection

I have a problem to attach a Database and insert all rows from attached databases to the main.

Here is my code.

```
public void selectOldDb(String dbName) throws Exception {
    createNewDB();
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    Connection connOldDb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ dbName);
    String newDbName = getDirToNewDb();

    newDbName = newDbName + "auftraege.db";
    Connection connNewDb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ newDbName);

    connNewDb.prepareStatement("ATTACH DATABASE \"" + connOldDb + "\" AS  fromDB").execute();

    connNewDb.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO main.auftraege  SELECT * FROM fromDB.SendeDS").execute();

    connNewDb.close();
    connOldDb.close();
}
```

I become this error when i try to insert.

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table:
>   fromDB.SendeDS)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1) the table doesn't exist, in which case you need to create it, 2) there is a typo in your database or table names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The table is there. I have testet it with a result set after the connection. But what do you mean with typo?

Comment: By a typo, I mean that you should double check that `SendeDS` is in fact the name of the table you are trying to query. Since I am a native English speaker, I see the possibility that you might have meant either `SendDS` or `SenderDS` instead. Such typos are very easy to overlook when you **know** what it should be. I'm just suggesting that you double check this.

Answer (score 4):

The `ATTACH DATABASE` command expects a file name, but you give it the representation of a `Connection` object.

You don't need `connOldDb`, just use `dbName` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot. it's so easy and is works fine. Here is my new code: connNewDb.prepareStatement(
  "ATTACH DATABASE '" + dbName + "' AS  fromDB").execute();

Comment: Do you even need to open a connection to old DB at all?

Comment: @Tacitus86 To quote the answer, "you don't need `connOldDb`".